# Move SSD from internal mSata to external USB enclosure: keep OP settings?

Tags: usb, ssd, enclosures

For some reason I am moving an internal Samsung 850 EVO SSD from the internal laptop m.2 port to an external USB 3.1 enclosure. It's not a system drive, just a data disk.
Samsung Magician will no longer recognize the drive, and hence I won't be able to manage its settings. As I understand it, OP and other routine housekeeping duties are configured from Magician, but handled by the onboard controller, i.e. Magician is in essence just a UI to access internal settings onboard the SSD, right ?
Is it a correct assumption then that the last settings seen in Magician while the drive was mSata mounted will remain, and that specifically, OP (10%) and other optimization duties will continue to work just fine as previously when the drive is used as external USB 3 disk ?